# Searching table for fields using multiple possible combinations and wildcards

Tags: mysql

If in a simple customers table:

```
customers (first_name varchar(40), last_name varchar(40))
```

i would like to run a search by customer name, i can do:

```
[MYSQL...] WHERE (customers.first_name LIKE "%john%" OR customers.last_name LIKE "%john%")
```

However, if someone uses the search field in the front end to search for a full name, such as `john arbuckle`, i won't be getting any results.

What is the most effective and easiest way to run this query correctly in MySQL so that it can yield the desired results without losing the wildcard search capability?

The only thing i can think of is to split the string by whitespaces and run multiple logical comparison combinations for each string component. But is that really the way to go? Isn't there perhaps a way to combine fields when comparing their values?

Comment: If your input represents the start of a word (unlike `'%john%`, which will also find `demijohn`), you can try a [fulltext search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). It will find combination of words (and, or, not) over several columns in any order. But the input has to be the start of words.

Comment: Pretty interesting, thanks. I am considering changing it. Currently it is really a rather tolerant filter. It may be an issue if the user can't search for components of a name, but then again, who looks for a name by using a scrap of a first or last name that begins in the middle of either name. Makes no sense, or am i missing some use cases? I wonder.

Comment: Well, the most common problem with names is that they are often entered incorrectly, something neither `like` nor a fulltext search will help with. Most people searching for names are usually even surprised if they get results with the input somewhere in the middle, but in some cases they want it. Is it "McDonald" or "MacDonald" or "Mc Donald"? - Let's enter "Donald" - 0 results. It's up to you to decide (maybe check current searches). If you go for a fulltext search, make sure to disable the stopwords (or be aware of them) and reduce the minimal word length to (probably) 1.

Comment: That is some great input. Thank you! Please post an answer so i can accept, as i assume your reference to fulltext search is providing a satisfying solution.